# Fatal error: Uncaught Error in instagram crawler

Tags: php

i want to use https://packagist.org/packages/smochin/instagram-php-crawler

i downloaded that and  i made index.php in project

index.php :

```
<?php
$insta = new Smochin\Instagram\CrawlerTest;
```

i have this error but i dont know why !

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Smochin\Instagram\CrawlerTest' not
>   found in E:\xamppN\htdocs\insta\index.php:10 Stack trace: #0 {main}
>   thrown in E:\xamppN\htdocs\insta\index.php on line 10

[image: insta crawler folders]

Comment: Which framework are you using?

Comment: now i just run that without error without framework!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add following line to your code

```
require_once DIR . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```